# Skip some columns when searching a matrix in a loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix, `c`, and I want to search many times for the index of the positive minimum element

```
d = min(c(c>0)); 
[x,y] = find(c == d);
```

but in the next search I want it to skip the old `y`.

how to do it?

I want to use `x` and `y` in some other calculation.

also I want to find this d minimum just within specific columns in the matrix c like:
           j from m+1 to n-1

please help

Comment: can't you change those values to `NaN`?

Comment: no i can't, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `mask = zeros(size(c));` before the loop.

And before finding the minimum use,

```
newc = c + mask;
d = min(newc(newc>0));
[x,y] = find(newc == d); 
mask(:,y) = NaN;
```

Comment: This is a good solution.  Setting `NaN` to those values that you have already seen will make `find` skip those locations.  +1.

Comment: thank youuuuu very much Kamtal, it is very handsome solution,,,

Answer (score 1):

I think you can update the c matrix. I mean:

> ```
> % In the loop, use it:
> [x,y]=find(c==d); 
> c(:, y) = [];
> ```

If c matrix is important, you can use a temporary variable equals to c, instead of using c.

Comment: By eliminating the column the indices will change in the next iteration.

Comment: He can also control it. For example,

for k = 1 : nRow
   for m = 1 : nCol
      [x,y]=find(c==d);
      c(:, y) = [];
      nCol = nCol - 1;
   end
end

Comment: Now you should know if the new `y` is before the eliminated column or after, if before, then no change is needed.

Comment: I didn' t understand what you meant exactly but the new y will be after.